# OAuth 2.0 Flow: Server-side web apps - YouTube API V3 permanent connection

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Maintain permanent user connection with YouTube API V3, without requiring repetitive authentication.

When requesting authorization with "access_type = offline" the API requires authorization again the next day. I need a permanent connection to the YouTube channel.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately this community is english-only so please ask your question in english.

Comment: Oauth is not "permanent" anyhow. You need to use techniques like "refresh token" to "keep alive"